# How to Pause and Resume Uploading process in iOS application?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I am working with an iOS application in which i have to upload the images on service (Facebook) from my iOS application.When i start uploading i want the functionality to Pause and Resume method while Uploading. I don't know how to do these functionalities? please help me out if you have any information.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using? AFNetworking? ASIHTTP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `NSURLSessionUploadTask` for uploading a file. `NSURLSessionUploadTask` class is inherited from `NSURLSessionDataTask : NSURLSessionTask : NSObject`.

And `NSURLSessionTask` provides Controlling the Task State

> – cancel
>   – resume
>   – suspend

useful links:  <[NSURLSessionTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTask_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSURLSessionTask)>
 [NSURLSessionUploadTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionUploadTask_class/Reference/Reference.html)

Try to implement this.

If you are using `AFNetworking` you can also achieve the same by using `AFHTTPRequestOperation`.

Comment: NSURLSessionUploadTask is only available for iOS 7??

Comment: Yes these are available in iOS 7.0 and later.

Comment: I mean to say before iOS7? iOS 6?